# Can't I use Code First fluent API with .NET Portable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, portable-class-library, ef-fluent-api

I have created a Portable Class Library targeting `.NETPortable, v4.0`

In the following class

```
public class AddressConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Address>
    {
        public AddressConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("Addresses");
            HasKey(c => c.Id);
        }
    }
```

at row `HasKey(c => c.Id);` 
visual studio complaints about

```
The type 'Expression<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. 
You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

What am i missing here?

The `App.config` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

while the `packages.config` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="portable40-net45+sl5" />
</packages>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Nikolaus What do you mean? I have included it in the question

Comment: Which version of VS do you use?

Comment: @Nikolaus 2015.

Comment: Can you add your project.csproj where all the refences are listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is a bit misleading here. When you just install EF via NuGet:

`Install-Package EntityFramework`

NuGet will report it as installed:

```
Adding package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' to folder '\\psf\home\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Solution2\packages'
Added package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' to folder '\\psf\home\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Solution2\packages'
Added package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' to 'packages.config'
Executing script file '\\psf\home\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Solution2\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\init.ps1'
Executing script file '\\psf\home\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Solution2\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\install.ps1'
```

the two scripts above would modify your proj file and `app.config` as well as `package.config` files, however, the actual dll will not be referenced.

If you check the content of the `packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib` you would find two folders with binaries (`net40` and `net45`).

In fact, portable profiles **are not supported by the EF** at all. You may want to consider using EF7.

You probably have referenced one of `.NET40` or `.NET45` DLLs manually. And now you're facing the problem with API mismatch here.

Another option is to rethink the architecture of your application. You can keep the business logic in the PCL, abstract away the work with a storage and inject the abstraction into the business logic class.

The actual implementation of that abstraction mentioned above you'd have to keep in the .NET 4.5 project.

Without knowing any details about your project, that's all I can suggest.